# CummeRbund csHeatmap: Way to adjust gene id text sizes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor

I was wondering if someone knew of a way to alter the gene id text labels for the heatmap generated by `csHeatmap()` function in the R package CummeRbund? I know it's a ggplot object, but I can't find a way to either 1) extract the gene ids in the order they are presented in the image or 2) modify their relative sizes. Right now, the text size is too large to be readable.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Think I figured this one out after a bunch of Google-ing.  You basically pass the theme to the object just like you would in ggplot...

```
hmap <- csHeatmap(myGenes,cluster='both')
hmap <- hmap + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14),axis.text.y=element_text(size=6))
```

Where myGenes is the name of your CuffGeneSet.

Good luck.